# Error creating flutter app for iOS - Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

--------------------------- Error Mensage:

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2022-06-19 14:50:18.899 xcodebuild[39895:226134] Requested but did not find extension point
with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-19 14:50:18.899 xcodebuild[39895:226134] Requested but did not find extension point
with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in
com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-19 14:50:19.885 xcodebuild[39895:226172]  DVTAssertions: Warning in
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-20038/DTDeviceKitBase/D
TDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008020-0008459A36B8003A was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x11d73a5d0>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600003501ec0>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any
useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/xk/24s15qjs3js_pbq9z13b7km00000gn/T/flutter_tools.XpLwrY/flutter_ios_build_temp_d
irundHWt/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_apple-1.2.2/ios
/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:157:21: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                    ^~~~~~~
                    openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS1
5.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note:
'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_apple-1.2.2/ios
/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:157:21: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                    ^~~~~~~
                    openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS1
5.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note:
'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes
/CameraPlugin.m:596:13: warning: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use atomic_compare_exchange_strong() from <stdatomic.h> instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, newBuffer, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
            ^
In module 'Darwin' imported from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes
/CameraPlugin.m:9:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS1
5.5.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomicDeprecated.h:548:6: note:
'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier( void *__oldValue, void *__newValue, void * volatile
*__theValue );
        ^
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes
/CameraPlugin.m:806:11: warning: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use atomic_compare_exchange_strong() from <stdatomic.h> instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(pixelBuffer, nil, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
          ^
In module 'Darwin' imported from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes
/CameraPlugin.m:9:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS1
5.5.sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomicDeprecated.h:548:6: note:
'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier( void *__oldValue, void *__newValue, void * volatile
*__theValue );
        ^
2 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
In file included from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/MLKVisionImage+FlutterPlugin.m:1:
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.h:12:22: warning: unused function 'getFlutterError'
[-Wunused-function]
static FlutterError *getFlutterError(NSError *error) {
                     ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.m:1:
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.h:12:22: warning: unused function 'getFlutterError'
[-Wunused-function]
static FlutterError *getFlutterError(NSError *error) {
                     ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/MLKVisionImage+FlutterPlugin.m:1:
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.h:12:22: warning: unused function 'getFlutterError'
[-Wunused-function]
static FlutterError *getFlutterError(NSError *error) {
                     ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.m:1:
/Users/pivajr/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mlkit_commons-0.2.0
/ios/Classes/GoogleMlKitCommonsPlugin.h:12:22: warning: unused function 'getFlutterError'
[-Wunused-function]
static FlutterError *getFlutterError(NSError *error) {
                     ^
1 warning generated.
ld: warning: ignoring file
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage,
file is universal (x86_64,arm64) but does not contain the armv7 architecture:
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLImage/Frameworks/MLImage.framework/MLImage
ld: warning: ignoring file
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitCommon/Frameworks/MLKitCommon.framework/M
LKitCommon, file is universal (x86_64,arm64) but does not contain the armv7 architecture:
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitCommon/Frameworks/MLKitCommon.framework/M
LKitCommon
ld: warning: ignoring file
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitFaceDetection/Frameworks/MLKitFaceDetecti
on.framework/MLKitFaceDetection, file is universal (x86_64,arm64) but does not contain the
armv7 architecture:
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitFaceDetection/Frameworks/MLKitFaceDetecti
on.framework/MLKitFaceDetection
ld: warning: ignoring file
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitVision/Frameworks/MLKitVision.framework/M
LKitVision, file is universal (x86_64,arm64) but does not contain the armv7 architecture:
/Users/pivajr/Desktop/siscop/siscop-app/ios/Pods/MLKitVision/Frameworks/MLKitVision.framework/M
LKitVision
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightCheek", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthRight", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthLeft", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEye", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftCheek", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightEar", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeNoseBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeUpperLipTop", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKModelDownloadDidFailNotification", referenced from:
      -[GenericModelManager manageModel:call:result:] in
      google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
      -[GenericModelManager receiveTestNotification:] in
      google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeUpperLipBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowTop", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowTop", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeRightEye", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeNoseBridge", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLeftCheek", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKFaceDetector", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLowerLipTop", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEar", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLowerLipBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowBottom", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEye", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeFace", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKVisionImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_commons(MLKVisionImage+FlutterPlugin.o)
      __OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MLKVisionImage_$_FlutterPlugin in
      google_mlkit_commons(MLKVisionImage+FlutterPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightEye", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceLandmarkTypeNoseBase", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKFaceContourTypeRightCheek", referenced from:
      ___57-[GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in
      google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_MLKModelDownloadDidSucceedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GenericModelManager manageModel:call:result:] in
      google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
      -[GenericModelManager receiveTestNotification:] in
      google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKModelDownloadConditions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKFaceDetectorOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_face_detection(GoogleMlKitFaceDetectionPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKModelManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_mlkit_commons(GenericModelManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/xk/24s15qjs3js_pbq9z13b7km00000gn/T/flutter_tools.XpLwrY/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirundHWt/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightChe

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthRight

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthLeft

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEye

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftCheek

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightEar

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeNoseBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeUpperLipTop

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeMouthBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKModelDownloadDidFailNotification

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeUpperLipBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowTop

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowTop

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeRightEye

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeNoseBridge

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLeftCheek

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MLKFaceDetector

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLowerLipTop

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEar

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLowerLipBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowBottom

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeLeftEye

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeFace

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MLKVisionImage

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeRightEye

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceLandmarkTypeNoseBase

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKFaceContourTypeRightCheek

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MLKModelDownloadDidSucceedNotification

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MLKModelDownloadConditions

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MLKFaceDetectorOptions

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MLKModelManager

Encountered error while building for device.
--------------------------------------------------- End of Error Mesage.

Any idea what could be happening and how to fix it?
Tks!

Comment: This error occur when a use:     flutter build ios
When i use  flutter run. its works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting podfile.lock, pods folder and .symlinks folder did not work for me. i didnt add settings for armv7 devices, adding that setting to Podfile worked for me.

https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues/97

Answer (score 4):

Delete Podfile.lock, pods folder and .symlinks folder. Now run `pod install` turn open the runner.workspace file in xcode and build it once. Once it's built successfully in xcode it should start working by build ipa too